# Fastest way how to find matched value in 2d arrays

Tags: c, arrays

What is the absolute fastest way to find matched values in 2d array?

lets say i have array `int arr[2][2]={{1,5},{2,2},{1,5}}`
and i want to find all values that match {1,5} , ofc the array will be much longer. What is the fastest way to do so?

Comment: what is the nature of the numbers (1, 5 etc).  are they all single digits .. do they have a limit?

Comment: You may introduce some kind of scalar to check if two pairs of numbers are the same or not. The scalar shall also let you knwo if one pair is less than the other. In that way you may then employ any kind of balanced binary tree to fetch the same pair as provided in logarithmic time.

Comment: no they are not single digs , those numbers will be random from 1 to 10000000000

Comment: That definition is not correct; you have three elements of two.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no other information, the fastest way is simply checking each element until you find it or have checked all of them.

Retrieval of elements becomes much faster if you have some control over how the array is created. For example, keeping the elements sorted according to some criteria would allow a binary search (e.g. using ISO C `bsearch()`).

If you can even drop the array requirement, you could use a hash table. There are techniques to retrieve values from hash tables guaranteed to only need two seeks.

In the end, "All optimization is an exercise in caching."